# If I don't compress a plain text file in Android, will it be compressed in the APK anyway?

Tags: android, zip, apk

I'm debating with myself whether or not to compress a plain text file I'm including in my application that is about 1.5 MB.  I can compress it to 400k with zip and unzip it in the application, but that's just one more thing to mess with.  If I don't do that, will it get compressed anyway in the APK?  Is there a special place I could put it to make this happen?  I'm really only concerned with download size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files are compressed based on their extension:

```
/* these formats are already compressed, or don't compress well */
static const char* kNoCompressExt[] = {
    ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif",
    ".wav", ".mp2", ".mp3", ".ogg", ".aac",
    ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".mid", ".midi", ".smf", ".jet",
    ".rtttl", ".imy", ".xmf", ".mp4", ".m4a",
    ".m4v", ".3gp", ".3gpp", ".3g2", ".3gpp2",
    ".amr", ".awb", ".wma", ".wmv"
};
```

[Source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=tools/aapt/Package.cpp#l24)

If it's not one of those it will be compressed when building the apk.

Comment: I'm not a C++ guy and can't tell whether this applies to resources or assets or both?

Comment: That's actually a good question... i'm not sure. But you could try it using ant projects. aapt usually prints on the commandline for each file if it compresses or skips it. Or just open the apk file with your favorite zip tool and take a look. Apk files are just zip archives after all.

Comment: The code that was posted looks like it just applies to assets.

Comment: How come? I'm pretty sure it applies to `raw` and `drawable` too

Comment: Another question: if the APK is a ZIP (I know it is, I've opened them before) -- why would you compress a file that's inside it? Isn't it already compressed?

Comment: That's what the original question is about isn't it? The build system just tries to avoid to compress compressed stuff since it's kinda pointless.